# gateway time out error in php wamp server

Tags: php, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, wampserver, timeoutexception

I am getting a timeout error in a long running php script. I tried to set the execution time by using the following code:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200);
```

also i tried to set the max_execution_time in apache conf file also. But the issue was not resolved.Still had the same issue. There is a firebase cloud messaging module inside the script which pushes some data to an android device. When I comment this part of the code. The gate way timeout error is not showing. But that code is important in the script and can not comment. What can be the reason for this? Can anyone please help me on this?

```
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                          $deviceid=$row["id"];
                          $regId=$row["regid"];
                        if($regId != null){
                          $json = $push->getPush();
                          $response = $firebase->send($regId, $json);
                        }

                        }
                    }
```

the script is actually inserting too many rows in a table and pushes that data  using fcm. if the inserting number of rows are less, then it is working.

Comment: how many rows in result? what lib are you using, if not a lib show $push and $firebase objects code. whats the error message after timeout, there must be a line number, what debugging have you done?

Comment: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` is for max execution time.

Comment: the script is actually inserting too many rows in a table. if the inserting number of rows are less, then it is working. do you know what can be the reason?

Comment: then do in batch or use a queue system

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is related to many records fetched from the result, can you please apply a limit of 2 in your SQL query and check once.

Comment: the script is actually inserting too many rows in a table. if the inserting number of rows are less, then it is working. do you know what can be the reason?

Comment: I think there may be a limit at firebase end that per second/minute only some of records are allowed, not sure but you should check on there documentations

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you have to reset execution time limit in every iteration, like this:

```php
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    set_time_limit(1200);
    // ...
}
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php